# Radiometric corrections with R

Tags: r, satellite-image, landsat

I am trying to convert Landsat 8 files to reflectance via R / RStoolbox

I am using a script with the following code:

```
metaData  <- readMeta("LC08_L1TP_183033_20210623_20210630_02_T1_MTL.txt")
lsat <- stackMeta("LC08_L1TP_183033_20210623_20210630_02_T1_MTL.txt")
lsat_sref <- radCor(lsat, metaData, method = "dos")
```

I've got this error :

```
Error in CRS(paste0(c("+proj=", "+zone=", "+units=m +datum="), pars, collapse = " ")) :
  No spaces permitted in PROJ4 argument-value pairs: +proj= +zone= +units=m +datum=
```

Can you try to help me please ?

Comment: Hello, look there: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/390084/rstoolboxreadmeta-open-landsat-mtl-in-r-error-in-crs

Comment: Many thanks manro. I have already saw this page. But It didn't help me. Add raw=T works with the readMeta function, but not with the staskMeta function. So I dont' know how to go through. Have you an other idea ?

Comment: metaData <- readMeta("LC08_L1TP_183033_20210623_20210630_02_T1_MTL.txt", raw=T)
## this code goes well ##
lsat <- stackMeta("/Users/olivier/Documents/GEO/MASTER/M2/TELEDETECTION/SIG_TD1/Data_travaux/2021_06/LC08_L1TP_183033_20210623_20210630_02_T1_MTL.txt", quantity = "sre", allResolutions = T) ## I have an error here ##

Comment: No-no. I have never worked with this library. But I think, if you ask there: https://gis.stackexchange.com - your chances to achieve some answers are grown up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your second line of code. You need to change it as follows and it should work:

`lsat <- stackMeta(metaData)`

Please find below a little reprex to show you how it works:

**REPREX**

```r
library(RStoolbox)

mtlFile  <- system.file("external/landsat/LT52240631988227CUB02_MTL.txt", package="RStoolbox")
metaData <- readMeta(mtlFile)
lsat <- stackMeta(metaData)
lsat_sref <- radCor(lsat, metaData, method = "dos")

lsat_sref
#> class      : RasterStack 
#> dimensions : 310, 287, 88970, 7  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#> resolution : 30, 30  (x, y)
#> extent     : 619395, 628005, -419505, -410205  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : +proj=utm +zone=22 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#> names      :       B1_sre,       B2_sre,       B3_sre,       B4_sre,       B5_sre,        B6_bt,       B7_sre 
#> min values :   0.01327889,   0.00000000,   0.00000000,   0.00000000,   0.00000000, 293.37508120,   0.00000000 
#> max values :    0.2028536,    0.1935375,    0.2243498,    0.4356817,    0.3393489,  299.8284592,    0.2617160
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**Edit**

Output of `summary()`

```r
summary(metaData)
#> Scene:      LT52240631988227CUB02 
#> Satellite:  LANDSAT5 
#> Sensor:     TM 
#> Date:       1988-08-14 
#> Path/Row:   224/63 
#> Projection: +proj=utm +zone=22 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
#> 
#> Data:
#>                              FILES QUANTITY CATEGORY
#> B1_dn LT52240631988227CUB02_B1.TIF       dn    image
#> B2_dn LT52240631988227CUB02_B2.TIF       dn    image
#> B3_dn LT52240631988227CUB02_B3.TIF       dn    image
#> B4_dn LT52240631988227CUB02_B4.TIF       dn    image
#> B5_dn LT52240631988227CUB02_B5.TIF       dn    image
#> B6_dn LT52240631988227CUB02_B6.TIF       dn    image
#> B7_dn LT52240631988227CUB02_B7.TIF       dn    image
#> 
#> Available calibration parameters (gain and offset):
#>  dn -> radiance (toa)
#>  dn -> brightness temperature (toa)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**Edit 2**

I think I found your problem. When downloading from the site https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/ you normally get, in addition to the .mtl metadata file, a total of 12 radiometric bands (i.e. B1-B11, and a "dedicated assessment quality band"-i.e. Bqa). All these files must be in the same folder and you must not delete any of them (some of them are used for radiometric corrections). In other words, the package `RSToolbox` is expecting these different files.

If you do this, everything should work.

Here is an example (not a reprex) from a landsat 8 image that I downloaded and all the code works:

```r
library(RStoolbox)
metaData <- readMeta("DATA_09/Landsat8/Landsat8_RAW/LC08_L1TP_016030_20160927_20170220_01_T1_MTL.txt")

# NB : Please, note the presence of all the bands (B1-B11 + Band qa):

summary(metaData)
#> Scene:      LC80160302016271LGN01 
#> Satellite:  LANDSAT8 
#> Sensor:     OLI_TIRS 
#> Date:       2016-09-27 
#> Path/Row:   16/30 
#> Projection: +proj=utm +zone=18 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs

#> Data:
#>                                                   FILES QUANTITY CATEGORY
#> B1_dn   LC08_L1TP_016030_20160927_20170220_01_T1_B1.TIF       dn    image
#> B2_dn   LC08_L1TP_016030_20160927_20170220_01_T1_B2.TIF       dn    image
#> B3_dn   LC08_L1TP_016030_20160927_20170220_01_T1_B3.TIF       dn    image
#> B4_dn   LC08_L1TP_016030_20160927_20170220_01_T1_B4.TIF       dn    image
#> B5_dn   LC08_L1TP_016030_20160927_20170220_01_T1_B5.TIF       dn    image
#> B6_dn   LC08_L1TP_016030_20160927_20170220_01_T1_B6.TIF       dn    image
#> B7_dn   LC08_L1TP_016030_20160927_20170220_01_T1_B7.TIF       dn    image
#> B9_dn   LC08_L1TP_016030_20160927_20170220_01_T1_B9.TIF       dn    image
#> B10_dn LC08_L1TP_016030_20160927_20170220_01_T1_B10.TIF       dn    image
#> B11_dn LC08_L1TP_016030_20160927_20170220_01_T1_B11.TIF       dn    image
#> B8_dn   LC08_L1TP_016030_20160927_20170220_01_T1_B8.TIF       dn      pan
#> QA_dn  LC08_L1TP_016030_20160927_20170220_01_T1_BQA.TIF       dn       qa
#>
#> Available calibration parameters (gain and offset):
#>  dn -> radiance (toa)
#>  dn -> reflectance (toa)
#>  dn -> brightness temperature (toa)

lsat <- stackMeta(metaData)
lsat
#> class      : RasterStack 
#> dimensions : 504, 541, 272664, 10  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#> resolution : 30, 30  (x, y)
#> extent     : 318195, 334425, 4737735, 4752855  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : +proj=utm +zone=18 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#> names      : B1_dn, B2_dn, B3_dn, B4_dn, B5_dn, B6_dn, B7_dn, B9_dn, B10_dn, #> B11_dn 
#> min values :  8492,  7617,  6777,  6026,  5290,  5185,  5142,  4995,  22328,  #> 20666 
#> max values : 19081, 19935, 21595, 22716, 27590, 38013, 39165,  5105,  30111,  #> 27137 


lsat_sref <- radCor(lsat, metaData, method = "dos")
lsat_sref
#> class      : RasterStack 
#> dimensions : 504, 541, 272664, 10  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#> resolution : 30, 30  (x, y)
#> extent     : 318195, 334425, 4737735, 4752855  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : +proj=utm +zone=18 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#> names      :       B1_sre,       B2_sre,       B3_sre,       B4_sre,        B5_sre,       B6_sre,       B7_sre,       B9_sre,       B10_bt,       B11_bt 
#> min values : 1.078127e-01, 7.822588e-02, 5.389152e-02, 3.082883e-02, 8.681202e-03, 5.291948e-03, 3.968224e-03, 0.000000e+00, 2.847589e+02, 2.830717e+02 
#> max values : 4.347280e-01, 4.464235e-01, 5.032560e-01, 5.323340e-01, 6.762622e-01, 9.449113e-01, 9.547490e-01, 3.183901e-03, 3.039071e+02, 3.018956e+02
```

Comment: Hi @Olivier Theureaux, if my answer solve your problem, please mark it as accepted to make it easier for other users to find the right answers. If you do not please write what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks lovalery. Unfortunately it didn't work. I have a new error # Erreur dans file.exists(file) : argument 'file' incorrect

Comment: O.K. That's another problem. The error message you get means that the file "LC08_L1TP_183033_20210623_20210630_02_T1_MTL.txt" is not accessible. There are two possibilities: either the file name contains an error in your code, or the file is not in your working directory. In the latter case, you must set the working directory with the command `setwd()` (indicate the full path to the folder containing the file you want to read between the brackets) NB: when you indicate the path e.g. C:/documents/mydirectory put slashes (i.e. "/") and not backslashes (i.e. "\"). Let me know if it works.

Comment: metaData <- readMeta("LC08_L1TP_183033_20210623_20210630_02_T1_MTL.txt", raw=T)

Comment: this works fine

Comment: after I use that : lsat <- stackMeta(metaData)

Comment: After that I have this error : error # Erreur dans file.exists(file) : argument 'file' incorrect

Comment: So, it's not about the directory or the file name ?

Comment: it's more about the stackMeta function, what do you think ? Thnaks for your help lovalery

Comment: A little weird. Two actions to narrow down the problem: (i) Could you give me the output of the code `summary(metaData)` , and (ii) did you manage to run the full reprex I provided or are you experiencing the same problem with the landsat image taken from the `RStoolbox` package?

Comment: the landsat image taken from the RStoolbox works well =>>>> library(RStoolbox)
> mtlFile  <- system.file("external/landsat/LT52240631988227CUB02_MTL.txt", package="RStoolbox")
> metaData <- readMeta(mtlFile)
> lsat <- stackMeta(metaData)
> lsat_sref <- radCor(lsat, metaData, method = "dos")
> lsat_sref
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 310, 287, 88970, 7  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent     : 619395, 628005, -419505, -410205  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

Comment: (i) summary  : > summary(metaData)
            Length Class      Mode
PRODUCT_CONTENTS             1      data.frame list
IMAGE_ATTRIBUTES             1      data.frame list
PROJECTION_ATTRIBUTES        1      data.frame list
LEVEL1_PROCESSING_RECORD     1      data.frame list
LEVEL1_MIN_MAX_RADIANCE      1      data.frame list
LEVEL1_MIN_MAX_REFLECTANCE   1      data.frame list
LEVEL1_MIN_MAX_PIXEL_VALUE   1      data.frame list
LEVEL1_RADIOMETRIC_RESCALING 1      data.frame list
LEVEL1_THERMAL_CONSTANTS     1      data.frame list
LEVEL1_PROJECTION_PARAMETERS 1      data.frame list

Comment: Apparently, the problem comes from your image because the output of your 'summary()' does not look good (see Edit above). Would it be possible for you to make your image accessible to try to find the problem?

Comment: My images ? I have 5 spectral bands from Landsat 8. LC08_L1TP_183033_20210623_20210630_02_T1_B2, LC08_L1TP_183033_20210623_20210630_02_T1_B3, LC08_L1TP_183033_20210623_20210630_02_T1_B4, LC08_L1TP_183033_20210623_20210630_02_T1_B5, LC08_L1TP_183033_20210623_20210630_02_T1_B7

Comment: I can send you these files via wetransfer, if you want ?

Comment: O.K. for we transfer. Please add the file .txt with metadata. Don't know if I will be able to solve your issue but will give it a try.

Comment: You can download my files here :  https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d5e2737c1e08e81374b3c1e56e1b8a2720211012175336/4d9eb986516cbb9e88caaad34cf084a820211012175354/06010a

Comment: O.K. I think I found the problem. Please find my answer above as edit2 . Test with your own image (if necessary, re-upload your image to get all the bands, cf. above) and everything should work :-). If something doesn't work, let me know. If all is fine, please mark the answer as "accepted" to make it easier for other SO users to find the right answers. Cheers.

Comment: Everything works very well lovalery ! Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad that I could help you. Please mark the answer as accepted so that other SO users can benefit from this answer if they are  experiencing the same problem. Cheers